# Order in writing composed morphisms

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

When we have a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ between two sets, and we want to explicit that we are applying it to some element $x \in A$, we write $f(x)$. After this, is natural to write $f(g(x))$ when we are compounding functions, and when we use the $\circ$ symbol, $f \circ g$.

The reason why write $f(x)$ instead $(x)f$ is unknown to me; but, of course, after learned the entire life to write in the first way, I use this way.

But, when you start to compound arrows in a sistematically way (i.e. studying category theory) you start to think that this was a **bad** choice.

[image: Compounding two morphisms]

Bother me this compose be $g\circ f$ instead of the (much more comfortable to the brain) $f \circ g$. Of course, you can kill the circle too, and write the even more confortable $fg$. We are talking about **arrows**, and arrows have **direction**!

But is not a good choice to use at the same time the "natural" and nonstandard compose and the notation $f(x)$; The first time I realized it was when I was writing a report, and I was going to talk about group action, and representations of the group of automorphisms (was a disaster). After, I partially understood why it was a bad idea:

On the category of sets, **Set**, we call a *point* an final object $P$. Of course, these are the sets with only one element, and are all isomorphic. An element on a set $S$ is an morphism $x:P \rightarrow S$; if we have a morphism $f:S \rightarrow T$, so the image of $x$ by $f$ is an element of $T$, and, of course, this guy is the compose of both $x$ and $f$.

[image: xf and not fx]

and, if we want to use the confortable nonstandard notation of composed, we have to write $xf$ instead $fx$. I have no doubt that this way to write composed morphism is much better, allowing the brain to think on more interesting and important stuff instead "how to write this and what are the domain and codomain". But I admit that I fell like a goddamn fundamentalist having to write $xf$, since $f(x)$ by itself don't bother at all.

So the questions are:

There exists more people awkward with the standard way of write composed functions/arrows/morphisms?

There are more arguments in favor to some notation or another?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Slightly offtopic: Using the same notation for composition and application (e.g., as you do, $fg$ and $xf$) is a recipe for disaster once higher-level functions appear. Either you need parentheses around the $x$ in $xf$, or a $\circ$ sign in $fg$.

Comment: You are certainly not the only person using the "reversed" convention for application and composition of maps. It was popular for a while in the 20th century, and people like Herstein used it in (some of) their textbooks. Group theorists sometimes still use it, confusingly, for the elements of the symmetric group (confusingly because almost noone bothers to tell the reader which convention he uses). I suspect that the standard notation being $f(x)$ has to do with the fact that we think of $f(x)$ as "$f$ of $x$", a (sort of) genitive construction.

Comment: Another argument for the "reverse" (compared to the traditional) notation is that it gives a more natural composition rule for relations: With the usual rules, you get $a(R_1\circ R_2)b \iff \exists c: cR_1b\land aR_2c$. It  would be much more natural to define it as $a(R_1\circ R_2)b \iff \exists c: aR_1c\land cR_2b$. But with the usual composition rule, that would not reduce to the usual function composition. It would, instead, reduce to the reverse function composition.

Comment: I discuss a bit with some friends of mine wheter is better to know first, the element or the function that will act on the element. I think that the element first, because when you have to say the function, you have to put variables to complete the hole of the element with variables (like f(x) =x² + 5x). But is not much strong to me, I think that (x)f or f(x) by itself are equal.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: But that's exactly what we do with operator notation on linear spaces: $Av$ is the application of the linear operator $M$ to the vector $v$ (in finite dimension: multiplication of the matrix M with the vector v), while $AB$ is the composition of linear functions (matrix multiplication). The point is, you have to know what sort of object you are dealing with (another example: if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars and $v$ is a vector, then $(\alpha\beta)v$ also involves two different operations; one field multiplication, and one scalar multiplication of a vector).

Comment: @celtschk: It kind-of works with matrices because they are not very high-level. But when your maps are polymorphic and things get coerced, ambiguities creep in. For example, for every set $S$, we can define a map $\Delta_S : S \to S \times S,\  s \mapsto \left(s,s\right)$. Then, for a map $f : T \to S$, the map $\Delta_S \circ f : T \to S \times S$ is not the same as the pair $\Delta_{S^T} \left(f\right) \in S^T \times S^T$. If you omit the subscripts (which is usually done -- that's the "polymorphy" part), you better not omit the $\circ$ or the parentheses. I have definitely ...

Comment: ... seen less artificial examples in literature on categories and/or Hopf algebras, but I don't remember them. This is similar to the classical confusion between the tensor product of two linear maps $f : M \to N$ and $f' : M' \to N'$ as a map $f \otimes f' : M \otimes M' \to N \otimes N'$ and their tensor product as a tensor $f \otimes f' \in \operatorname{Hom}\left(M,N\right) \otimes \operatorname{Hom}\left(M',N'\right)$.

Comment: For what it's worth, Paul Taylor uses $f;g$ as a synonym for $g\circ f$ in *Practical Foundations of Mathematics*. I thought it was a nice convention to allow the more understandable ordering without it getting confused with the traditional ordering.

Comment: Of course you are free to reorient your arrows instead

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the usual order of composition is awkward. Unfortunately, it is hard to imagine how to change this mistake. Here are some links which are related to your question:

- [Category theory text that defines composition backwards?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258344/category-theory-text-that-defines-composition-backwards)
- http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/composition#Notation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

For example, you will find that "reverse Polish has been found to lead to faster calculations", and that "Many people who agree that diagrammatic order is 'better' on its own merits nevertheless believe that trying to change the established 'classical' order of composition creates more confusion than it removes".

By the way, I have recently written an introduction to (weak) $2$-categories with the usual composition notation, and it was really just a big mess. For instance, try to write down the interchange law without confusing yourself or the reader! I was really wondering why in their texts almost all category theorists just cope with this mess instead of changing it. Then I chose the diagrammatic order of composition and have written $f * g$ (not $f;g$ which is kind of ugly) for the composition (first $f$, then $g$). I also wrote $(x)f$ instead of $f(x)$, because then we have $(x)(f * g)=((x)f)g$. The result was unusual, but also enlightening, because now every formula and every part of a formula could be read and simultaneously evaluated from left to right, which is what we do anyway in most countries around the world.

Notice how natural $(x)f$ really is: First, I have my $x$, and then I plug this $x$ into $f$. This is how calculations work. The notation $f(x)$ is not so good because we have to put $f$ on a stack while evaluating this expression (either by our mind, or by a parser).

Actually RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) is completely free of brackets, but I would suggest to add brackets for readability and also still use infix notation for binary opaerations. I would prefer $2+3$ to $2 \,3 + $.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. I always use diagrammatic order, when making category theory notes. I feel like it is much easier to read and write (proofs in particular). I like writing $f»g$ for "forward composition", the notation is derived from the OCaml programming language.

Comment: I wish I could do that. I have learnt the usual composition order and used it so many years that it is hard for me to overcome it. Also, on the internet, when writing about math, I don't want to confuse people ...

Comment: The downside is, of course,  that I have to translate everything when showing it to other people or in particular to ask a question here. But it still feels more natural and easier to use to me, maybe also because I'm just starting to learn math.